# Postman doesn't have consistent behavior with files in response

Tags: python, flask, postman

I'm trying to, separately, send two files from Flask to Postman.

```
flask.send_file('C:\A.pdf', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="A.pdf")
```

```
flask.send_file('C:\B.doc', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename="B.doc")
```

Postman opens the "Save As" dialog when receiving the pdf file. But it trys to display the raw data when receiving the doc file.

Why is there a difference? I need it to be consistent and always offer to save the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Flask, it's just how Postman decides to display the data it receives. You can't ultimately control what a client does with the data you send, the most you can do is say it's an attachment, as you've done, and hope the client does what you want with it. Browsers *should* always offer downloads when sending an attachment.